# Python: complete a given url with full address

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a url cnn.com when i feed it in a browser, it finds http://www.cnn.com as correct url.

However

```
r = requests.get('www.cnn.com')
```

gives

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'www.cnn.com': No schema supplied
```

Error

Is it possible to detect the right url just like a browser does?

Comment: I don't think browsers do anything special when you feed them an incomplete url, except 1. trying to connect to the domain using IPV6 ("https"), and if it doesn't work, fall back to IPV4 ("http").

Comment: @doukremt: IPv6 vs. IPv4 has nothing to do with https vs. http. You can use either schemes with either protocol.

Comment: At least Mozilla actually has the rules documented somewhere. Something like this: If there is no scheme, assume https or ftp if port 443 or 21, otherwise http; if there is only one component to the host, add .com to the end; if the lookup fails and there are only two components to the name (possibly after adding .com) add www. to the beginning; … If you really want all those rules, you're going to have to read the docs and code them yourself. But do you really want them, or just something simple like "add http:// to everything"?

Comment: … and of course those rules are hard to find nowadays, since every browser tries autocomplete and/or autosearch before falling back to guessing…

Comment: @abarnert: relax buddy.

Comment: @doukremt: You should really know at least the basics of what you're talking about before trying to teach other people. If someone comes away from this site thinking that https means IPv6, you've done them a major disservice.

Comment: @abarnert: tell me more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the module you are using does not want to guess the scheme, so you *have to* provide it. If you build an interface yourself and want your users to be able to omit the scheme, you need to implement some "intelligent" approach yourself. A way to do so would be to use http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html, check if a scheme was given within the URL. If no scheme was provided, add your desired default scheme (e.g. `http`) to the `ParseResult` object and get the modified URL via `ParseResult.geturl()`.

Comment: Better, if the schema is blank, just fill it in, then use `ParseResult.geturl()` to rebuild the proper URL.

Comment: a string search to check whether there is a MissingSchema error OR checking string.startswith('http://www.') or ('http://') something like that can be done as a workaround. how would that work for most of the cases if anyone supplies a url

Comment: @user2290820: `startswith('')` is always true, and `startswith('http://') does the wrong thing for `'https://example.com'`. Which is exactly why Jan-Philip Gehrcke used `urlparse` here—getting it right manually is not completely trivial, so why not use the batteries included with Python that have already been built and tested?

Comment: @abarnert okay, i still don't get it. i enter urlparse.ParseResult.geturl('google.com') and it gives me TypeError

Comment: You don't call `geturl` on the _class_. You call `urlparse` to get a `ParseResult`, then replace the scheme (if empty), then call `geturl` on the result. Jan-Philip Gehrcke's answer, like most good answers on SO, won't help you if you're not trying to learn anything and just want code you can copy and paste without understanding it

Comment: @abarnert we should have tried setting the scheme on a ParseResult... :-) Just came across this and unfortunately `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Right, `ParseResult` is immutable; you have to create a new copy with the attribute replaced. Much like with a string or a tuple or any other immutable type. In fact, `ParseResult` _is_ a `tuple` subclass, at least in 2.7 and 3.3, so you can do it _exactly_ the same way as a tuple, but it's probably not the cleanest way. If you're doing a lot of this, you may want to add a method or helper function like [this](http://pastebin.com/ShHpGM8P) to make it more concise and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, or at least it's possible to make good guesses and test them. 
To make a good guess, you could start by looking for "http://" at the start of a URL, and add it if it's not there. To test that guess, you could try to hit the resulting domain and see if you get a successful response. .